# Local network blocking our subdomain 'client.henrybuilt.com'

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

Do you have any idea why my local Seattle office network or firewall would be blocking my subdomain client.henrybuilt.com?

All I know is:

- I can access it from anywhere other than the office network just fine
- I can access presentation.henrybuilt.com and henrybuilt.com just fine on the office network
- I can access it via a proxy website
- The guys in our NY office can access it just fine
- The local network is called ‘henrybuilt.local’ which leads me to believe there is a folder or something on the local server interfering?
- It’s not a problem with the web hosting service or code. It’s definitely something local.

I don’t really know anything about this stuff unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

If you type "ping client.henrybuilt.com" what does it say? I suspect this is not a firewall issue, but a name resolution one. If client.hernrybuilt.com does NOT return `63.134.214.34` from the place it's not working you need to figure out how to make it resolve properly.

You can also test this by trying `http://63.134.214.34` - if that works it's not being blocked at the network level, once again it's a name resolution issue.